# The set $I$ as indices, e.g. $\{U_i | i \in I\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I have seen this a few times now, expressions of the form e.g. $\{U_i | i \in I\}$. For example in these MSE questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157381/u-i-i-in-i-is-an-open-cover-of-x-show-that-dimx-sup-dim-u-i-i) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954740/if-u-i-i-in-i-is-a-countable-collection-of-open-sets-must-cap-i-in) [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628428/what-result-is-left-bigcup-i-in-ia-i-right-sum-i-in-i-a-i). My question is: What is $I$ been used to represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$I$ is an indexing set. For example, if your family of sets is countable, one can use $I$ to be the set of natural numbers. Since $I$ is not necessarily countable, the general indexing set is expressed as a set $I$.

Answer (score 0):

$I$ is an arbitrary index set, to index the collection of sets $U_i.$